# Server - Client impletmentation using RMI over the Internet

Tags: java, client-server, rmi

I implemented very basic RMI server client application. It works perfectly in LAN. It doesn't work over the Internet though. What are the things i should consider to make it work over the Internet(Programtically). In future i want to use Client call backs too. So, is it possible using Java - RMI? if yes how ?

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since I worked with RMI, but as far as I remember Java's RMI only works in the same sub-network. So it won't work directly over the internet.

You will need to use a different Technology like XML over HTTP, REST, Soap or similar Protocols.

If you cannot (or don't want to) change your application, you will probably need to implement some kind of proxy that talks RMI to your application and something different to the clients in the internet. But I would not recommend to do that